# How can i navigate to another tab bar item by a button click in first tab?

Tags: ios

I have a situation to navigate from first tab item to second tab item by a button click in first tab. how can i do that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call `-setSelectedIndex:` in your button click handler.
This would select the 3rd tab.

```
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex: 2];
```

Please note that documentation is your friend: [UITabBarController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

In addition you can try this:

```
[tabBarController setSelectedViewController:(UIViewController *)[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex: 2]];
```

Comment: holex thanks for your answer, i can now able to navigate to third tab  but the problem is tab item remains in same tab. Is there solution to change the tab item also ?

Comment: I updated my answer - hope it helps. What exactly do you mean by "tab item remains in same tab"?

Comment: Actually tab item changes but the image that i used instead of default tab bar image doesn't change. I have changed the image in the tabBarController:shouldSelectController delegate method. Then In tabbarcontroller.viewcontroller is always null if i try to call the that delegate method. so it always  change the selectedindex as 0. so Image dosent change. same image remains.

Comment: Hmm, this looks like an implementation problem. You could open a new question and you should definetly post some relevant code to get a good answer for this one.